# my form.is _valid() function is returning False value in django . please check the below files to know more about the issue

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Below is the code in models.py file
it has some fields
models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Measurement(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    distance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"distance from {self.location} to {self.destination} is {self.distance}"
```

in views.py i am tryin to insert some data from the form into the table

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Measurement
from .forms import MeasurementModelForm

# Create your views here.
def calculate_distance_view(request):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Measurement,id=2) 
    form = MeasurementModelForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        print("valid")
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.destination = form.cleaned_data.get('destination')
        instance.location = 'san francisco'
        instance.distance = 5000.00
        instance.save()
    else:
        print("not valid")
        print(form.errors)

    context = {
        'distance' : obj,
        'form' : form,
    }
    return render(request,'measurements/main.html', context)
```

main.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
calculate distance
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
{{ distance }}

<hr>
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off"></form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >confirm</button>
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

in the console it is prinnting blank for form.errors

python console
C:\Users\vishnu.vijaykumar\Desktop\src>python manage.py runserver

Watching for file changes with StatReloader

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

September 26, 2020 - 13:46:55

Django version 3.1.1, using settings 'distance_proj.settings'

Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

not valid

[26/Sep/2020 13:47:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1394

Comment: can you show me your forms.py

Comment: hey got the mistake i made .. i had an extra closing form tag in main.html